# sbt-ensime not playing nice with SBT name hashing

Tags: scala, sbt, ensime

Following the installation guide [here](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) to install ENSIME for Emacs. I added the `addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt" % "0.1.5")` line in my `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` file and started SBT in a SBT multi-project.

On start I get the following error:

```
/myprojectpath/project/project/build.sbt:3: error: value withNameHashing is not a member of sbt.inc.IncOptions
incOptions := incOptions.value.withNameHashing(true)
                               ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

If I remove the `addSbtPlugin` line then SBT starts up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look from [#1592](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1592) that this is a known issue and the workaround is to blow away your `~/.ivy2`.

Comment: Ended up doing this https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1592#issuecomment-95178818 which seemed to work. Thanks for pointing to the issue ticket!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is coming here after moving to 1.x of sbt (like I did 20 mins ago), you don't need `incOptions.value.withNameHashing(true)` anymore.

> incOptions.value.withNameHashing(...) option is removed because name hashing is always on.

From: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html#sbt+1.0.0